# Is there a way to find the number of unique days for a specific bird species in my data set and in turn how many weeks it is present in?

Tags: r, count

I am trying to gain data that would look something like this:

| Species | Days | Weeks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alexandrine Parakeet | -- | -- |
| Acrocephalus sp. | -- | -- |

My data set has the species name and the observation date with 129952 rows of data. it looks something like this:

```
# A tibble: 129,952 × 6
   `TAXONOMIC ORDER` `COMMON NAME`    `SCIENTIFIC NAME` `OBSERVATION COUNT` `OBSERVATION DATE`   ...6
               <dbl> <chr>            <chr>             <chr>               <dttm>              <dbl>
 1             10444 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2018-01-21 00:00:00    NA
 2             27278 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2019-10-19 00:00:00    NA
 3             22631 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2019-10-19 00:00:00    NA
 4             21017 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2020-12-13 00:00:00    NA
 5              1498 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2020-12-13 00:00:00    NA
 6              1871 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2021-01-31 00:00:00    NA
 7              1871 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2021-01-31 00:00:00    NA
 8              5468 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2021-02-14 00:00:00    NA
 9             30260 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2022-10-12 00:00:00    NA
10             10393 Acrocephalus sp. Acrocephalus sp.  1                   2019-09-17 00:00:00    NA
# ℹ 129,942 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I am trying to gain from that data something like the proposed calculation below: where the "eBird_data" is the data frame the date present is the "observation date" and the species name is in the "common name" column.

count(eBird_data, number of unique days from "observation date for Alexandrine Parakeet from "Common name")

Then once I get the number of unique days the bird showed up then use the observation dates to calculate the number of weeks the bird was present during the year.

I have tried using the COUNT function but it was built for version 4.2.3 so it is not allowing me to use it as I have updated R. I also tried nrow but these could be the right function just the wrong format for finding the answer.

I have no idea if I am on the right track or where I should start. I know for example that in Excel this worked for the data I needed for data but it would take forever.

| Species | The name mentioned in the Excel sheet | Unique dates for species | Therefore it is present |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Accipiter sp. | 9 | 6 | 6 days in 2018-2022 |

for weeks it would be present 6 different weeks between Jan2018 and Dec2022 based on the observation dates:

```
# A tibble: 129,952 × 6
   `TAXONOMIC ORDER` `COMMON NAME`    `SCIENTIFIC NAME` `OBSERVATION COUNT` `OBSERVATION DATE`   ...6
               <dbl> <chr>            <chr>             <chr>               <dttm>              <dbl>
 1             10444 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2018-01-21 00:00:00    NA
 2             27278 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2019-10-19 00:00:00    NA
 3             22631 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2019-10-19 00:00:00    NA
 4             21017 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2020-12-13 00:00:00    NA
 5              1498 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2020-12-13 00:00:00    NA
 6              1871 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2021-01-31 00:00:00    NA
 7              1871 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2021-01-31 00:00:00    NA
 8              5468 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2021-02-14 00:00:00    NA
 9             30260 Accipiter sp.    Accipiter sp.     1                   2022-10-12 00:00:00    NA
10             10393 Acrocephalus sp. Acrocephalus sp.  1                   2019-09-17 00:00:00    NA
# ℹ 129,942 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: The count() function is part of the dplyr package, you need to have this installed and then load that package so you can use the count function. i.e. it should be available to you, it isn't restricted to version 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

You need the package `dplyr` loaded and once that is available then you can count both distinct dates and weeks (for calculating week package `lubridate` is needed) as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Assumes data is stored in variable 'data'
result <- data %>%
  mutate(`OBSERVATION WEEK` = week(`OBSERVATION DATE`)) %>%
  group_by(`COMMON NAME`) %>%
  summarise(
    num_days = n_distinct(`OBSERVATION DATE`),
    num_weeks = n_distinct(`OBSERVATION WEEK`)
  )
```

Comment: I think I found the issue with the code not running the packages are giving warnings saying it is built under r version 4.2.3 so I am going to reload r and try to update it again hoping that solves the issue.

Comment: I have gotten an error in the week function:                                    
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `OBSERVATION WEEK = week("OBSERVATION DATE")`.
Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format                                                I have tried to clarify in the week string that it is year-month-date but it is not liking that. any suggestions?

Comment: Sigh. Not really. If the data is bad it needs fixing or you have to detect and ignore the bad bits,which then affects the validity of your results. Suggest you research fixing bad strings to dates. Maybe a new question in that topic with representative data sample.